# filtering the model based on a relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So my code is

```
$categories=Category::where('user_id', $store->id)->whereHas('childrenCategories', function($q) use ($id){
            $q->where('user_id', $id);
        })->orwhereHas('products', function($q) use ($id) {
            $q->where('auth_id', $id);
        })->with('products', 'childrenCategories')->latest()->get();
```

I want to get all children categories with and products with given id but this code doesn't seem to work. As children categories with user_id other than id are also being returned. Sorry, I am relatively new to Laravel. And I thought this would be a good platform to ask. Also, I can share the relationships if you want me to.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the `whereHas` part has nothing to do with the `with` part ... you would also have to filter the eager loading, the `with` part; you can reuse those closures if you would like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with the following. Thanks, @lagbox for your time.

```
$categories = Category::with(['childrenCategories' => 
$childrenClosure = function ($query) use ($id) {$query->where('user_id', $id);}, 'products' 
=> $productsClosure = function ($query) use ($id) {$query->where('auth_id', $id);}])
->where('user_id', $store->id)
->where(function ($query) use ($childrenClosure, $productsClosure) {$query->whereHas('childrenCategories', $childrenClosure)
->orWhereHas('products', $productsClosure);})
->latest()
->get();
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of the code you provided?